# Gold tag dupe-hammer posts a comment then removes it immediately

Tags: feature-request, tags, comments, vote-to-close, dupehammer

When a normal user votes to close as a duplicate, a comment is posted.

When the question is closed, the comment is removed.

The same happens with someone with a gold tag - a comment was posted then immediately deleted.

Is there any way that there could be a check - it's quite odd to see a comment message, then the comment goes, and the post is closed after a refresh.

Comment: That's the normal flow of how comments about the master question work, gets posted, gets deleted

Comment: @random yes, but different for a mod interestingly. an exception *could* be made.